# <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Baslica')}> doesn't navigate any screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I tried to give an onPress action to one of my custom button made with `TouchableOpacity`. It is supposed to navigate me to another screen. I did how exactly i did at other screens but this time it doesn't work and don't get any error as well. On the Navigation.js, when i give initialRouteName manually, screen appears, but when i click on the button, nothing happens.

Home Screen:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar, Image, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Baslica')}>
                <ImageBackground
                    source={require("../../assets/HomeScreen/baslicaButton.png")}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    style={styles.baslicaButton}
                    imageStyle={styles.baslicaButton_imageStyle}
                >
                    <Image
                        source={require("../../assets/HomeScreen/baslicaText.png")}
                        resizeMode="contain"
                        style={styles.baslicaText}
                    ></Image>
                    </ImageBackground>
                </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
    );
}
export default HomeScreen;
```

Navigation JS:

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import IntroScreen from './src/screens/IntroScreen';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import BaslicaScreen from './src/screens/BaslicaScreen';

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
        Intro: IntroScreen,
        Home: HomeScreen,
        Baslica: BaslicaScreen
  },
  {
      initialRouteName: "Intro",

  }
);

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

Comment: Dear @Emirhan, did you wrap your app by your AppContainer at root level like <AppContainer>...</AppContainer> ?

Comment: Than you for your answer and edit @Nostromo ! and im pretty new at react native so im not 100% sure what you mean. But i think i didnt wrap my app with AppContainer. I will take a quick look what you mean

Comment: I looked for it and looks like i didnt wrap it with AppContainer

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your components between AppContainer tags in your root component similar with below so that the `navigation` object become aware of the react-navigation context.

```
import AppContainer from './navigation'; // your navigation.js file

export default class RootApp extends React.Component {

    ...

    render() {
        return <AppContainer>
        // the rest of your other components here
        </AppContainer>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you Should use `navigation` param like this:

```
    this.props.navigation.navigate("yourScreen", { ParamName: Valu });
```

Edit Your code like This:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar, Image, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
               this.props.navigation.navigate('Baslica')}>
                <ImageBackground
                    source={require("../../assets/HomeScreen/baslicaButton.png")}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                    style={styles.baslicaButton}
                    imageStyle={styles.baslicaButton_imageStyle}
                >
                    <Image
                        source={require("../../assets/HomeScreen/baslicaText.png")}
                        resizeMode="contain"
                        style={styles.baslicaText}
                    ></Image>
                    </ImageBackground>
                </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
    );
}
export default HomeScreen;
```

and Edit this code like that :

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import IntroScreen from './src/screens/IntroScreen';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import BaslicaScreen from './src/screens/BaslicaScreen';

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
        Intro: {screen:IntroScreen},
        Home: {screen:HomeScreen},
        Baslica: {screen:BaslicaScreen},
  },
  {
      initialRouteName: "Intro",

  }
);

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

Comment: i Edit answer and navigation screen code changed , test it , maybe work:)